# Connecting to exchange server with powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to connect to my exchange server (currently using a hybrid build of o365+exchange)

```
$usercredential = Get-Credential
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName microsoft.exchange -connectionuri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $usercredential -Authentication basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession
```

When using this I'm able to connect however it'll return

```
cmdlet Import-PSSession at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Session:
```

I've gone through get-help without much luck but whatever is inputted will return the error

```
Import-PSSession : Cannot bind parameter 'Session'. Cannot convert the "" value of type "System.String" to type 
"System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession".
```

What am I overlooking?

edit:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$s = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName "Microsoft.Exchange" -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-Module o365
Get-mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -ResultSize 10000
```

Using this I was able to bypass using exchange and just communicate with o365 and get the details I was looking for.